# jquery selector for all checked checkboxes that are not disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

how can I find all checkboxes, that are checked and **not disabled**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
return !this.disabled && this.checked;
})
```

Comment: Yes, but losing `:checked` from the selector and making the filter function `!this.disabled && this.checked` would improve performance a great deal.

Comment: why exactly? I would think that the selector engine would do it faster than my function. Nevertheless it is easier to understand, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Because browsers don't understand `:checked`, so jQuery has to do it itself, which is slow. Adding an extra boolean check is much quicker.

Comment: @lonesomeday `:checked` is a normal CSS selector, not a jQuery extension.

Comment: @Esailija Indeed, my mistake. Still, it didn't work in IE<9, so there's still a speed improvement in that browser.

Comment: @lonesomeday `Still, it didn't work in IE<9, so there's still a speed improvement in that browser` What exactly were you talking about? Why are you comparing IE to a web browser... two different things altogether (pun intended) ;). Nonetheless, your point on speed is valid for real web browsers too.

Answer (score 52):

Like so:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not(":disabled")...
```

This finds fields that are `input`s, with type `checkbox`, which are checked, and not disabled. If this does not work, you should use an attribute check:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not("[disabled]")...
```

Or, as @lonesomeday astutely pointed out, you can combine it into one selector:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked:not(:disabled)")...
```

I've put together a proof-of-concept [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMWGU/).

Comment: There's no point in using two separate selectors here. You may as well do `input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not([disabled])`.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').not(":disabled");
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vvVH/)

Comment: you have to use the .filter() function like in my response

Answer (score 6):

You can use this selector..

```
​$('input[type=checkbox]:checked:not(:disabled)')​
```

Check This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WwE6F/)

Answer (score 1):

how about `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked:enabled")` ?