# prevent already disabled checkbox from being checked when click on checkAll

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Below is the code i am using for check all the check boxes.

```
jQuery("#checkAll").on('click',function() { // bulk checked
            var status = this.checked;
            jQuery(".selectRow").each( function() {
                jQuery(this).prop("checked",status);
            });
        });
```

But already disabled checkbox is also checked when i click on CheckAll link. How to stop already disabled checkbox from being checked when click on checkAll link? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Answer: The whole code looks like this`

```
jQuery("#checkAll").on('click',function() { // bulk checked
                var status = this.checked;
                jQuery(".selectRow").not(":disabled").each( function() {
                    jQuery(this).prop("checked",status);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Use the not(":disabled") filter with your current code and it will leave out those checkboxes which are disabled.

```
jQuery(".selectRow").not(":disabled")...
```

See this question which looks very similar: [jquery selector for all checked checkboxes that are not disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358231/jquery-selector-for-all-checked-checkboxes-that-are-not-disabled)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:not` selector to select every `checkbox` that doesn't have the `[disabled]` attribute:

```js
$('#checkAll').on("click", function(event){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:not([disabled])').prop('checked', true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" /><br />
<input id="checkAll" type="button" value="check all" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example on how it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(doReady);

        function doReady()
        {
            jQuery('#checkAll')
                    .on("click",
                            function (event) {
                                var $that = null;
                                event.preventDefault();
                                    jQuery.each(jQuery(".selectRow"),
                                            function (index, value) {
                                                $that = jQuery(value);
                                                if (!$that.is(':checked') && !$that.is(":disabled")) {
                                                    jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                                                }
                                            }
                                    );
                            }
                        );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="checkAll" name="checkAll">check</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectRow" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectRow" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectRow" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectRow" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectRow" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectRow" disabled="disabled" />
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it is better to assign the same jQuery selector to a variable in order to avoid getting a 2nd time over the whole DOM tree.

And also note that you missed out a curly brace on your code example.